# Image navigation with arrays next() and prev() links

Tags: php, arrays, image, loops, navigation

I'm trying to use this function for image navigation:

```
function array_key_relative($array, $current_key, $offset = 1, $strict = true) {
  // create key map
  $keys = array_keys($array);
  // find current key
  $current_key_index = array_search($current_key, $keys, $strict);
  // return desired offset, if in array, or false if not
  if(isset($keys[$current_key_index + $offset])) {
    return $keys[$current_key_index + $offset];
  }
  return false;
}
```

I want to use it this way:

```
<?php 
$images = array();
foreach ($images as $key => $image)
$prev_key = $this->array_key_relative($images, $key, -1);
$next_key = $this->array_key_relative($images, $key, 1);
?>


<a href="<?php echo "image?id=".$images[$prev_key]->id; ?>">Prev</a>
<a href="<?php echo "image?id=".$images[$next_key]->id; ?>">Next</a>
```

The problem is when I press Next or Prev links its working only once, so for example if the current key is 1 if I press next will go to 2 but once i'm on 2 page the navigation stop working (doesnt go to 3, 4, 5, etc). 
Cound anyone point me to right direction? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your next_key doesn't include a + symbol on first look -

> $next_key = $this->array_key_relative($images, $key, +1);

But I would use

```
$next = $images++; 
$prev = $images--;


$next_key = $this->array_key_relative($images, $key, $next);
$prev_key = $this->array_key_relative($images, $key, $prev);
```